# Copy and paste Value and Format Only - Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to copy and paste just values and format - not formula..

E.G (A1 is a dynamic text):

A1 = "test"

A2 = **=A1**

I'd like to use a script that when activated it copy A2 format and text (in this case would copy "test" - not "=a1") to A3 .

I tried with "formatOnly:true , contentsOnly:true" - but it keep copying formula.

```
function Threebrow() {  
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('c');
  sheet2.getRange("a2").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7), {formatOnly:true , contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Formulas are also counted as content in this context.
The below function copies value and format of A2 to the lowest row in the first column.

```
function Threebrow() {  
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('c');
  var sourceRange = sheet2.getRange("a2");
  var targetRange = sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1);
  targetRange.setValues(sourceRange.getValues());
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly:true})
}
```

Comment: awesome - works great and its so much faster then copy cell by cell

Comment: How would you do this for an entire sheet? A1 to last column and row?

Comment: `getDataRange` instead of `getRange`.

Comment: Nice; But height of rows is not maintained.

Answer (score 0):

More information requested: my function is not working on line n°9

```
function CopyFormatting() {
//Déclaration des variables
var SheetResponse = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //Sheet of forms response
var LastRow = SheetResponse.getLastRow(); //last row of sheet (n)
var RefRow = SheetResponse.getRange("3:3"); //Row n°3 considered as reference

//Copy formatting to last row from reference row
RefRow.copyTo(LastRow, {formatOnly: true});
}
```